# iOS background audio recording after call

Tags: ios, audio-recording

I'm developing an iOS application that records audio in background. That's work fine.
The problem is when a call comes in: when i'm calling the app stops to record (that's fine) but when the call ends, I need that the app start to record again.

Is it possible ? How can I do this ?

Thanks to all.

**UPDATE**

I use AudioQueueNewInput to record audio. Now I'm trying to use this code to get incoming call:

```
AVAudioSession *session = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
NSError *categoryError = nil;
[session setActive: NO error: nil];
if (![session  setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord
               withOptions:AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionMixWithOthers
                     error:&categoryError]){
    NSLog(@"Error"); //no error
}
[session setActive: YES error: nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(handleAudioSessionInterruption:)
                                             name:AVAudioSessionInterruptionNotification
                                           object:session];
```

I can get the ends of call on handleAudioSessionInterruption by AVAudioSessionInterruptionOptionShouldResume, but how can I restart my audio recorder?

I tried to use to call AudioQueueStart again o simply same function that I use to start to record, but I can't see the red bar (mic in use) to know that app is recording. What's wrong ?

Answer (score 4):

Please see this  question:
[Can not restart an interrupted audio input queue in background mode on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9276546/can-not-restart-an-interrupted-audio-input-queue-in-background-mode-on-ios)

> Yes it is possible, but to reactivate the session in the background,
>   the audio session has to either set AudioSessionProperty
>   [kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideCategoryMixWithOthers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9276546/can-not-restart-an-interrupted-audio-input-queue-in-background-mode-on-ios)
>
> ```
> OSStatus propertySetError = 0;
> UInt32 allowMixing = true;
> propertySetError = AudioSessionSetProperty (
>                    kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideCategoryMixWithOthers,
>                    sizeof (allowMixing),
>                    &allowMixing);
> ```
>
> or the app has to [receive remote control command events](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/RemoteControl/RemoteControl.html):
>
> ```
> [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];
> [self becomeFirstResponder];
> ```

Comment: I tried to use AudioSessionSetProperty but seems it doesn't work. I use AudioQueueNewInput to record audio and I tried to set your code first to create the queue. I'm new in iOS world, so maybe this comment  it's stupid.

Comment: I don't know too much about AudioSessions, but do you get any errors, or does it just not work?

Comment: It doesn't work. After call app doesn't start to record.

Comment: I use AudioQueueNewInput to record audio.